# Yii2 ArrayHelper show parent category

Tags: arrays, yii2

I have page with parent page from other table. I want to show results with title of parent page in breaks like this 'Service page (Clinic 1)' ... Service page (Clinic 2) ... because now the users see only 'Service page','Service page' and do not know parent for everyone page. My parent page in database is `hospital_id`
my query is

```
$parentPagesArray[0] = Yii::t('app', 'app.main_page');
$parentPages = \backend\models\Page::find()->where('active=1')->orderBy('sort ASC')->all();
$parentPagesArray['----------------'] = ArrayHelper::map($parentPages, 'id', 'title');
```

and the view:

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 tooltip-info"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="<?=Yii::t('app','app.Tooltip page id_in')?>">
            <?php
            ?>
            <?=
            $form->field($model, 'id_in')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                'model' => $model,
                'attribute' => 'id_in',
                'data' => $parentPagesArray,
                'options' => [
                    'placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'app.select_an_option'),
                ],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true
                ],
            ])
            ?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ArrayHelper::map()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper#map()-detail) allows you to provide callback to generate title:

```
$parentPagesArray['----------------'] = ArrayHelper::map($parentPages, 'id', static function ($page) {
    $title = $page->title;
    if (isset($page->parent)) {
        $title .= " ({$page->parent->title})";
    }

    return $title;
});
```